# C# assign a value to the object property with parameters

Tags: c#, vbscript, gettype, invokemember, getproperty

I have an object in vbs:

```
 Msgbox myobject.parametro("parm")
```

I can use it in C# in this way:

```
Object test = myobject.GetType().InvokeMember("parametro", 
    BindingFlags.GetProperty, 
    null, 
    myobject, 
    new object[] { "parm" });

Messagebox.show(test.toString());
```

How can I in C# assign a value to the property?

For example:

```
myobject.parametro("parm")=725
```

Comment: what is `parametro`, and how is it declared? if you show us *what that is*, we can probably indicate how to invoke it properly

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you mean:

```
myObject.parametro["parm"] = 627; // set
var test = myObject.parametro["parm"]; // get
```

Answer (score 0):

Change BindingFlags to SetProperty

```
SomeClass c = new SomeClass();
c.GetType().InvokeMember("Prop", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, c, new object[]{ 1 });
```

Comment: In this way I assign the value 1 to the "c.Prop=1" but i need to write c.Prop("parm")=1